# Does spring boot (Spring 3) graphql support tracing between microservices?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql-java, spring-graphql

I'm using below micrometer dependencies along with spring boot graphql starter.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-observation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

When I use below graphqlclient to fetch data from one of my microservices I can see that traceId is being propagated for both services but unfortunately differently.

```
    @Bean
public HttpGraphQlClient dataServiceHttpGraphQlClient(@Value("${url}") String dataServiceUrl) {
    return HttpGraphQlClient.builder()
            .url(url)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
            .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json")
            .build();
}
```

This's how I execute it:

```
 public <T> Mono<List<T>> executeQuery(final String queryName,
                                      final String path,
                                      final Class<T> responseClass,
                                      final Map<String, Object> variables) {
    log.debug("Executing {} query: {}", path, queryName);

    GraphQlClient.RequestSpec document = graphQlClient.documentName(queryName);
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(variables)) document.variables(variables);

    return document.execute()
            .mapNotNull(response -> response.field(path).toEntityList(responseClass))
            .onErrorResume(error -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Error " + error.getMessage()))); //TODO custom exception

}
```

When I check the headers in my requested service, I can see that no tracing header is added.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured this out. There're two topics here first you must bind `WebClient.Builder` via Autowiring it since Spring handles the tracing itself.

Second there's a bug in the spring graphql https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-graphql/issues/675 So using `3.0.7-SNAPSHOT` for spring dependencies fixed it.

```
@Bean
public HttpGraphQlClient dataServiceHttpGraphQlClient(@Autowired WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder,
                                                      @Value("${url}") String url) {
    return HttpGraphQlClient.builder(webClientBuilder)
            .url(url)
            .build();
}
```

**UPDATE** 3.0.7 is now released, you don't need to use SNAPSHOT anymore.